# apply function for each subgroup

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can use loop function to calculate

```
apply(table(data$people,data$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

for each level of Colour. I mean, I want to calculate the above function for each level of Colour.

```
people <-c("R1","R2","R2","R3","R3","R4","R4","R4","R4","R3","R3","R3","R3","R2","R2","R2","R5","R6")
event<-c("a","b","b","M","s","f","y","b","a","a","a","a","s","c","c","b","m","a")
Colour<-c("red","blue","green","pink","red","blue","grean","red","red","black","pink","blue","blue","green","blue","green","green","red")

data<-data.frame(people,event,Colour)
```

Comment: Please leave the `algorithm` tag off as this question is not related to algorithm design.

Comment: What is your desired output? It's not very clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: Let me try to put words in your mouth and you tell me if I'm correct: For each `Colour`, you want to count the number of `people` at each `event` and summarize this as the average number of `people` at all *attended* events (only non-zero attendances included in the average). Is that it?

Comment: @ David Arenburg, For example when Colour="red" calculate the above function. Instead of using subset, I want to use loop function.

Comment: @ Gregor, I want to calculate the average of frequency of event (sum(event)/N=number of ids)) for each level of colour. We need to use the above function for calculating the average of frequency. Now I just want to calculate it for each level of  colour separately.   For better clarification: if Colour="red" calculate apply(table(data$people,data$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0])). If Colour="blue" calculate apply(table(data$people,data$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0])). But instead of getting subset, I want to use a loop function.

Comment: The best practice in R is to avoid loops if at all possible because they're absurdly slow [in R]. Instead, you need to vectorize your code. The `*apply` family of functions allow the similar functionality, as does `dplyr`, which is usually more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do your function to each group, let's first make it a function:

```
your_function = function(data) {
    apply(table(data$people,data$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
}
```

Then we can split your data up by Colour and apply your function to each sub-data-frame:

```
dat_split = split(data, f = data$Colour)
results = lapply(dat_split, your_function)

results
# $black
#   a   b   c   f   m   M   s   y 
#   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
#
# $blue
#   a   b   c   f   m   M   s   y 
#   1   1   1   1 NaN NaN   1 NaN 
#
# $grean
#   a   b   c   f   m   M   s   y 
# NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1 
# ...
```

Personally, I don't find this very friendly. `data.table` and `dplyr` make doing things to subsets of data frames easy. I would have used `dplyr` from the start, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(people, Colour, event) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>%
    group_by(Colour, event) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(n)) %>%
    tidyr::spread(key = event, value = mean)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 9]
#
#   Colour     a     b     c     f     m     M     s     y
#   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  black     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2   blue     1     1     1     1    NA    NA     1    NA
# 3  grean    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
# ...
```

Comment: If you use `sapply` instead of `lapply` in `results` in the first version, you'll get a much nicer looking table.

Comment: @Gregor, Just another question, when I apply your first solution on my data set it works, however for the second one I get this error:Error: All columns must be named
Any idea regarding that?

Comment: Haven't seen that error before. Do all your columns have names?