# R loop through multiple sub groups with using functions

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

Hi I am trying to learn how to loop through multiple groups within a data frame and apply certain arithmetic operations. I do not have a programming background and am struggling to loop through the multiple conditions.

My data looks like the following:

```
Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Indiv1=c(4,5,6,11,45,66,8,9,32,45)
Indiv2=c(7,81,91,67,12,34,56,78,90,12)
Category=c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1) 
Play_together=c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
Money=c(23,11,78,-9,-12,345,09,43,21,90)
z = data.frame(Event,Indiv1,Indiv2,Category,Play_together,Money)
```

What I would like to do is to look through each event and each category and take the average value of Money in cases where Play_together == 1. When Play_together==0, then I would like to apply Money/100.

I understand that the loop would look something like the following:

```
 for i in 1:nrow(z){
     #loop for event{
         #loop for Category{
              #Define avg or division function
         }
     }
 }
```

However, I cannot seem to implement this using a nested loop. I saw another post  (link: [apply function for each subgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756081/apply-function-for-each-subgroup)) which uses dplyr package. I was wondering if someone could help me to implement this without using any packages (I know this might take longer as compared to using R packages). I am trying to learn R and this is the first time I am working with nested loops.

The final output will look like this:
[image]

where for event 1, the following holds:

a) For cateory 1:

Play_together ==1 in row 1; we take the avg of Money value and hence final output = 23/1= 23

Play_together==0 in row 2; we take Money/100= 0.11

b) For category 2:
Play_together == 1 for all observations. We take avg Money for all three observations.

This holds similarly for Event 2. In my actual dataset, I have event = 600 and number of category ranging from 1 - 10. Some events may have only 1 category and a maximum of 10 categories. So any function needs to be extremely flexible. The total number of observations in my dataset is around 1.5 million so any changes in the looping process to reduce the time taken to carry out the operation is going to be extremely helpful (Although at this stage my priority is the looping process itself).

Once again it would be a great help if you can show me how to use nested looping and explain the steps in brief. Much appreciated.

Comment: your example output differs from sample data... (which has an event '3')

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Wimpel. I had to change the example data multiple times. I  changed it now.

Comment: You shouldn't be using loops for this, use `dplyr` or `data.table` packages, or in base R `aggregate` or `by`.

Comment: The eventual use for this is in a Gibbs sampling framework (Bayesian statistics) where I would need to follow this procedure. I was trying to break down the problem in a very simplistic way so that I can learn how to use nested loops in R. @Gregor

Comment: Unless you want to force R to move at a snail's pace, you need to use vectorization whenever available. So don't loop over every row, at least start your outer loop at the category level. You can have your outer loop be over Category, your inner loop be over Event, then show an attempt! It's really hard to know what you need help with when all you show is a bare skeleton without anything filled in.

Comment: And maybe start on a simple example? Can you get a working solution just considering Category and ignoring Event? That would be a good first step, that you could then modify.

Comment: That is actually a good suggestion. Let me try that. @Gregor

Comment: But if you're building a Gibbs sampler for data with 1.5MM observations, implementing it yourself in R is a painful and inefficient way to go. Use JAGS or BUGS or (not Gibbs, but usually more efficient) Stan. Use the highly optimized tools that are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R's `by`, the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` designed to subset dataframes by factor(s) but unlike `split` can pass subsets into a defined function. Then, run conditional logic with `ifelse` for *Final_Output* field. Finally, stack all subsetted dataframes for final object.

```
# LIST OF DATAFRAMES
by_list <- by(z, z[c("Event", "Category")], function(sub) {      
  tmp <- subset(sub, Play_together==1)
  sub$Final_Output <- ifelse(sub$Play_together == 1, mean(tmp$Money), sub$Money/100)
  return(sub)      
})

# APPEND ALL DATAFRAMES
final_df <- do.call(rbind, by_list)    
row.names(final_df) <- NULL

final_df 
#    Event Indiv1 Indiv2 Category Play_together Money Final_Output
# 1      1      4      7        1             1    23        23.00
# 2      1      5     81        1             0    11         0.11
# 3      2     66     34        1             1   345       217.50
# 4      2     32     90        1             0    21         0.21
# 5      2     45     12        1             1    90       217.50
# 6      1      6     91        2             1    78        19.00
# 7      1     11     67        2             1    -9        19.00
# 8      1     45     12        2             1   -12        19.00
# 9      2      8     56        2             1     9        26.00
# 10     2      9     78        2             1    43        26.00
```

Answer (score 2):

will something like this do?
I know it's using dplyr, but that package is made for this kind of jobs ;-)

```
Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Indiv1=c(4,5,6,11,45,66,8,9,32,45)
Indiv2=c(7,81,91,67,12,34,56,78,90,12)
Category=c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1) 
Play_together=c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
Money=c(23,11,78,-9,-12,345,09,43,21,90)
z = data.frame(Event,Indiv1,Indiv2,Category,Play_together,Money)

library(dplyr)

df_temp <- z %>%
  group_by( Event, Category, Play_together ) %>%
  summarise( money_mean = mean( Money ) ) %>%
  mutate( final_output = ifelse( Play_together == 0, money_mean / 100, money_mean )) %>%
  select( -money_mean )

df <- z %>%
  left_join(df_temp, by = c("Event", "Category", "Play_together" )) %>%
  arrange(Event, Category)
```

Comment: I like this solution as it is tidy, but my concern is you are dropping a lot information about indiv1 and indiv2

Comment: yes, but that is not your currently solution... I know that you can join it back on.

Comment: It gives me the result I want. But if you could also tell me how I would implement this through a loop, that would be awesome. The reason why I asked this question is that I would like to learn how to implement this using a loop (without taking the help of functions like dplyr etc). @Wimpel

Comment: @Prometheus i would never ever recommend using loops for this.. why bother? not needing for-loops is one of R's many strengths

Comment: @Wimpel the eventual use of this portion is to use this as part of a Gibbs sampling framework in a Bayesian regression model where I need to generate different latent values for each each observation. I was trying to break up the problem to a very simplistic form so that I did not overly complicate my question here. I will try and see if this solution works in my final model.